# 32.768 kHz schematic

Tags: crystal, esp32

I found a schematic and I want to reproduce it, in this part it has a crystal oscillator to run the processor, I design my PCBs with easyEda and print with JLCPCB. I never used a crystal oscillator, I assumed the capacitors are simple ceramic capacitors but when I upload my BOM and Pick and place to JLCPCB they only allow me to select a 12 pF crystal resonator, not a ceramic capacitor, is the schematic correct with crystal resonators instead of ceramic capacitors? In this case, what is its function?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: *12pF crystal resonator* 12 pF means that it is a **capacitor**, not a (crystal) resonator. Capacitors, crystals and resonators are **different devices**. This circuit is generally used to provide a clock signal to keep track of time (Real Time Clock).

Comment: "12pf crystal resonator" could be referring to something like this: https://lcsc.com/product-detail/_TKD-3225-40M-12PF-10PPM_C337678.html

Comment: Which component in your schematic is JLCPCB giving you trouble with, the capacitors C32 and C33 or Y2?

Comment: The capacitors C32 and C33, I don't know what type I shoud choose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a multilayer ceramic capacitor (MLCC) that has a dielectric type NP0 (also called C0G).

The size and manufacturer are up to you. The voltage rating of most parts like this will be more than adequate (usually 50V).

If I look at the basic parts available from JLCPCB  there are a number of choices in stock.

[image]

In this case your main choice is between 0402, 0603 and 0805 size.

Answer (score 2):

Ceramic is used for millions of things from insulators capacitors to resonators with the right mix of materials and geometry yet all behave differently.  Thus a ceramic FM IF resonator is different from a ceramic capacitor, although most ceramics (albeit one Np0/C0G) have a slight piezoelectric effect.

Some with PZT added , much more than others used for BBQ igniters *like the one I just salvaged from recycling trying to fix.* 8(

There are many types of resonators : MEMs, ceramic, tuning fork, RLC and crystal. Don’t confuse them even if they have an equivalent RLCC equivalent circuit.

In all cases they can oscillate in parallel resonance by putting 2 caps in series with ground thus the values are reduced like all caps in series.

- generally the C values chosen are twice the rated load capacitance.
- If you do not reduce the input C value by the few pF of that CMOS
  type, then it will run maybe 10 ppm faster than expected.

### Answer

- the caps are added to tune the resonator to the factory design and swamp any parasitic ~1pF connections to be more accurate. Like tuning the tension on a guitar string.

  - But over a tiny range.

[MEMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_system_oscillator) resonators are the most common choice for this frequency.

If you stated 24 pF for each capacitor for a 12 pF resonator or 21pF, 24 pF then it would be (more) correct.  Y is the correct ref Des. For a resonator. C for a capacitor. Y was originally used for crystals, before MEMs were invented, just like Y1. ;)

Perhaps the trend now is for MEMs to include a semiconductor to classify it as an Oscillator and discrete MEMs are becoming obsolete.  **The Op should TAKE NOTE that it is cheaper now to simply buy an oscillator and then you don‘t have to worry about picofarads..**  https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/sitime/SIT1533AI-H4-DCC-32-768E/13520060

https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/oscillators/172?s=N4IgjCBcoExgrABiqAxlAZgQwDYGcBTAGhAHsoBtEAZhgDoB2ANgYAIBrACQC8QTbGTABwcefGvRFdeAXRIAHAC5QQAVQB2AS0UB5DAFkCWPAFcATgRABfKySYoQmgCYqAtGEQQFyyCHGKAT3lLX2N0GyA

Comment: tuning fork crystals are still very common at 32.768 kHz.  only Murata seems to have MEMs at that frequency

Comment: @Jasen  Why aren’t you seeing the hundreds of MEMs parts that I see? https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/oscillators/172?s=N4IgjCBcoEwMxwBxVAYygMwIYBsDOApgDQgD2UA2iHAOwAsiAbAJwgC6JADgC5QgDK3AE4BLAHYBzEAF9pJAKwoQnKGC4rIYAAxa5IRkpEATPgFptELr0ggQJbgE9OBPljzpZQA

Comment: Because I searched for 32.768 kHz resonators.

Comment: Resonators are getting passé, when you can ignore parasitics and get better accuracy in the complete package and even make them programmable.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I suppose that the component I shoud choose are ceramic capacitors.